# 5 points on upvote?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, reputation

I only got 5 points on superuser for an upvote. Any ideas? I haven't met my limit yet.

Comment: why did this user leave?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you have, and then some - according to Jon Skeet's [rep tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?su=2066&mode=today&showzero=true&showflair=true), you've gained +215 points since 0:00 UTC.

Comment: Ah, its quite confusing. I was clicking the yesterday link.

Comment: I can confirm that. It looks like you hit your cap and then got an extra accepted answer.

Comment: I love the rep limit time frames...I am at my rep limit today on Meta and my "today" only says 17 rep gained.

Comment: @TheTXI: You reached the rep limit here *very* early today. You had (IIRC) 229 at about 8am UTC.

Comment: Jon: I remember at one point last night (EST) my "Reputation Gained" on the front of my recent activity read "317"

Comment: I very rarely bother with that bit, to be honest - I generally just use my tracker. I did take a snapshot one day when the "Yesterday" reputation tab (i.e. today + yesterday) on SO showed 1004. That was a good pair of days.

Comment: My ego has just been crushed yet again.